# BLOB android download and uploading to windows azure?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hey I'm creating a android application where I need to be able to download and upload blobs to my windows azure sql database from my android app can somebody explain to me how I can do a basic version of this?

Comment: Consider storing binary data in Azure Blob Storage instead of in SQL Database.  It's much cheaper and faster.  Store the image, get the key and store that in SQL.

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I added a link to some Azure/Android tutorials in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's two ways you could go with this.  One is to simply use the REST API to GET and PUT data.  For example, to upload a blob: PUT https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob.  To get the blob: GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob (where "myaccount" and "mycontainer" are configured by you in the portal)

How you GET or PUT would be up to you.

The other is to use the native API, which is documented here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/

In particular, how to *download* a blob: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/#DownloadBlob and how to *upload* a blob: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/#UploadBlob

## Update:

To get started with Android and Azure, this is a good place to start:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/android-samples/

Comment: How do I add the java sdk into my android app?